# Why do I always have to change the position of a sprite to something else before I can get the desired position to work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, position, coordinates

I personally think this is *really* ***really*** weird.

I was just developing a game using SpriteKit. I created a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` in order to create a sprite that shows how much time is left in the game, the score, etc. I called it `GameBanner`.

I am now trying to put an `SKLabelNode` in the top left corner of banner. I don't know the exact position of it so I wrote this:

```
timerTitle.position = //CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 
    timerTitle.frame.width / 2 + 20, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 
    self.frame.height / 2 - 20)
// timerTitle is the label node that shows "Time Left"
```

But I can only see the banner's background image on the screen, not "Time Left". I think this is because somehow I set the position of `timerTitle` to be outside of the banner.

Then I thought, well, this is to much trouble for me to figure where it should be, let's "trial and error" this!

I first tried with (0, 0). It puts the label right in the center. Then I tried these:

1. (-100, 0) - Label not visible ("Maybe it's too far left?" I thought)
2. (-40, 0)  - Label in about the center, a little offset to the left ("If -40 is *this* little left, then -100 would work!", I thought)
3. (-100, 0) - Label visible, seems in the correct position. ("Wait a minute! Why the first time it didn't work?", I thought)
4. (The same thing happens when I tried with (-160, 0) and (-160, 20), i.e. The first time it is not visible, changed it to another value and run it, changed it back to (-160, 0) and it worked)

I hope you can understand my problem with screenshots:

This is when I first set the position to (-160, 20):

[image]

Then I changed it to (-160, 0), it shows up:

[image]

After that, I changed it back to (-160, 20) and it magically works!

[image]

Here is the `GameBanner` class:

```
class GameBanner: SKSpriteNode {
    let timerTitle = SKLabelNode(text: "Time Left:")
    let timerLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "60")
    let collectedBlocksLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Collected Blocks")
    let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Score:")

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //Call this initializer with Position: (302.08, 860.78), Size: (604.16, 100.0) to reproduce
    convenience init(position: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
        self.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "banner"), color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: size)
        self.position = position
        configureLabels(timerTitle, timerLabel, collectedBlocksLabel, scoreLabel)
        // This is the part that doesn't work as I have said above
        timerTitle.position = CGPointMake(-160, 20)

        addChild(timerTitle)
        //addChild(timerLabel)
        //addChild(collectedBlocksLabel)
        //  addChild(scoreLabel)

        zPosition = 10000
    }

    private func configureLabels(labels: SKLabelNode...) {
        for label in labels {
            label.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.fontName = "Chalkduster"
            label.fontSize = 25
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the background image of the banner. Maybe this matters:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue is related to [ignoresSiblingOrder](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/ignoresSiblingOrder) property.

Currently, you have something like this :

parent (which is GameBanner) has `zPosition` set to 10000.

label (timerTitle) is added to the parent, and has default zPosition set to 0.0, which means, the rendering (global) zPosition will be 10000 + 0 = 10000. Means, it will be rendered sometimes before (below), and sometimes after (above) its parent.

Try to set zPosition of a label explicitly, to place it above its parent:

```
 convenience init(position: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
        //...
        timerTitle.zPosition = 1
       //...
        zPosition = 10000
    }
```

Now, the global rendering zPositiot will be 10000+1 = 10001, means, that label will be always on top of the banner image.

About `ignoresSiblingOrder` property:

> The default value is NO, which means that when multiple nodes share
>   the same z position, those nodes are sorted and rendered in a
>   deterministic order. Parents are rendered before their children, and
>   siblings are rendered in array order. When this property is set to
>   YES, the position of the nodes in the tree is ignored when determining
>   the rendering order. The rendering order of nodes at the same z
>   position is arbitrary and may change every time a new frame is
>   rendered. When sibling and parent order is ignored, SpriteKit applies
>   additional optimizations to improve rendering performance. If you need
>   nodes to be rendered in a specific and deterministic order, you must
>   set the z position of those nodes.

More about how node tree is rendered:

[Creating The Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW18)